# Convert delimited string to Expando Object

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, expandoobject

I lave a dictionary like this -

```
Dictionary<string, Object> dict = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
dict.Add("event.data", "data");
dict.Add("event.Location", LocObj);
dict.Add("event.Details.Cost", CostObj);
```

I am trying to merge this with the existing json structure -

```
{
   "event" : {
       "name" : "Hello World",
       "tags" : [tags]
    }
    "sponsors" : {
       ...
    }
    "OtherObj" : {
       ...
    }
 }
```

I am trying to use ExpandoObject and then inject it into the original json, like this-

```
 foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Object> kvp in dict) {            

        var newObj= new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
        newObj.Add(kvp.Key, value);         

        existingObject.Merge(JObject.FromObject(newObj), new JsonMergeSettings
        {
            MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
        });
    }

   Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(existingObject));
```

But when it gets serialized **event.Location** does not show up inside the existing event tag, instead it adds a new key called **event.Location**.

```
{
   "event" : {
       "name" : "Hello World",
       "tags" : [tags]
    },
    "event.Location" : { ... },   <---------------
    "event.data": { ... },        <---------------        
    "event.Details.Cost" : { ... }<---------------        
    "sponsors" : {
       ...
    },
    "OtherObj" : {
       ...
    }
 }
```

How do I fix the Expando obj creation to fix this?

Comment: A key, in JSON terms as well as JavaScript object terms, may be any string, including strings with dots in them. If you want a new property on the `event` object, you'll need to build that out. I suggest using a dynamic object, a la `var newObj = new { event = new { Location = LocObj, Details = new { Cost = CostObj } } }`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am getting the dictionary from a different developer and it is dynamic. I was looking for a generic way to implement this and get all the properties merged.

Comment: what is existingObject?

Comment: @ZakkDiaz It is just JObject existingObject= JObject.FromObject(myobject); .. MyObject has all the fields I pasted in my first Json..

Comment: Is MyObject some arbitrary/dynamic type? Or is it a known type?

Comment: LocObj doesn't seem to be serializing, I'm wondering if that type is private & Newtonsoft can't serialize it

Comment: @ZakkDiaz No I have the class definition on my side .. I am trying to merge the data sent by other developers before serializing the json.

Comment: @ZakkDiaz It is serializing, my problem is that I want it inside the existing event as a property..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208734/discussion-between-zakk-diaz-and-user9969157).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below program. This will show an example of a working merge and breaking merge. The difference is how the object is structured. In one case, there is "Event.Location" which does not work. In the other case, the "Event" object contains a "Location" and it correctly nests in the JObject's merge operation.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace DynamicSerial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myObject = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
            myObject.Add("Id", 1);
            myObject.Add("Event", new { Name = "SomeName", Id = 2 });

            var mergeObject = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
            mergeObject.Add("Event", new { Location = new { Name = "SomeLocation", Id = 3 } }); //WORKS
            //mergeObject.Add("Event.Location", new { Name = "SomeLocation", Id = 3 }); //DOES NOT WORK

            JObject myDynamicObject = JObject.FromObject(myObject);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> kvp in mergeObject)
            {

                var newObj = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
                newObj.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

                myDynamicObject.Merge(JObject.FromObject(newObj), new JsonMergeSettings
                {
                    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Merge
                });
            }

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDynamicObject));

        }
    }
}
```

The resulting JSON

```
good:
{"Id":1,"Event":{"Name":"SomeName","Id":2,"Location":{"Name":"SomeLocation","Id":3}}}
bad:
{"Id":1,"Event":{"Name":"SomeName","Id":2},"Event.Location":{"Name":"SomeLocation","Id":3}}
```

In conclusion, you should change

```
Dictionary<string, Object> dict = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
dict.Add("event.data", "data");
dict.Add("event.Location", LocObj);
dict.Add("event.Details.Cost", CostObj);
```

To

```
Dictionary<string, Object> dict = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
dict.Add("event", new { data="data", Location=LocObj, Details=new { Cost=CostObj } });
```